# How to count when colum value is true or 1

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I got this database. [image]

Later I add some more columns in table PlayerMatch (times (when something happend), YellowCard, RedCard).

Before I add this columns to the database, this SELECT works and count result like this:

```
SELECT A.MatchDate, B1.Name AS HOMETEAM, C1.Goal AS GOAL_HOME, C2.Goal AS GOAL_AWAY, B2.Name AS AWAYTEAM
 FROM Match A
 INNER JOIN Team AS B1 ON A.HomeTeamId = B1.TeamId
 INNER JOIN Team AS B2 ON A.AwayTeamId = B2.TeamId
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(Goal) AS Goal
            FROM PlayerMatch 
            INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerId = PlayerMatch.PlayerId
            GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId) C1 ON A.MatchId = C1.MatchId AND A.HomeTeamId =C1.TeamId
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT MatchId, TeamId, COUNT(Goal) AS Goal
            FROM PlayerMatch 
            INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerId = PlayerMatch.PlayerId
            GROUP BY MatchId, TeamId) C2 ON A.MatchId = C2.MatchId AND A.AwayTeamId =C2.TeamId
```

So before I got output like this: `01.01.2001. Bayern 2 2 Barcelona`

Now this SELECT doesn't work correctly. It count goals even when Goal = NULL, so I got wrong results. How can I correct this?

Comment: You can use 'SUM(CASE WHEN Goal IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Goal'

Comment: Why is Goal a true/false? How do you handle multiple goals in a game? Honestly I think you need to normalize this. I would want at least one more table to hold MatchEvents. This table would have the PlayerID and MatchID and the EventID (events would be another table for goals, yellow card, red card, sub etc). That way you can track all the statistics. Goal just isn't a true/false value for a player.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)